# load a resource file in a static method

Tags: java, static, resources

I need to create a command line application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Loading lenders data from the CSV file
    DataLoader.loadData(lendersList);
}
```

The loadData(lenderList) is static and needs to load in memory the content of a file

```
public class DataLoader {

protected static void loadData(List<Lender> lendersList) {

    try {
        CSVReader reader;
        //reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ConstantData.CSVFILE));
       reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.txt")));**
....    
}
```

Since the method is static I cant load the resource (config.txt).

Does anybody know what is the way to load the resource in this kind of situations?

Comment: Since the method is static I cant load the resource (config.txt). ??? Please explain ...

Comment: I get this error: non static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a compile error. Replace

```
getClass()
```

with

```
DataLoader.class
```

If I guessed wrong, please explain what error you get and post the corresponding message and/or stacktrace. Please don't add it as comment, the formatting there is horrible for this kind of thing.

Comment: I managed to get it working by using            reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ConstantData.CSVFILE)));
 which I believe is in line with Lothar answer

Comment: Same thing as long `Main` and `DataLoader` are coming from the same ClassLoader. `getClass()` is short for `this.getClass()`. There is no `this` in a static method hence the compile error.